# Json retrieve last 4 digits

Tags: json, jackson, schema, jackson-databind

I have this JSON query:

```
 "creditdebitIndicator": "#{ $doc.settlement.acctgEntry.?[account.account_number_withoutleadingzeros == $account_id][0].crDrIndicator }"
```

I want to retrieve last 4 digits of account.account_number_withoutleadingzeros and $account_id and then compare the values. I have trues using [-4] and $substring but I am getting errors. The values are String.
What changes can I do to get last 4 digits?

Comment: so convert the string to int and then compare

Comment: I am new to JSON, but the thing is I just want to compare last 4 digits. How will that be possible?

Comment: Find the last 4 chars using `string lastFour= json.Substring(json.Length - 4)`. After this convert it with `int x = Int32.Parse(lastFour)`

Comment: @alex I am trying to make the changes in the query itself. Is there any way?

Comment: something like: (account.account_number_withoutleadingzeros)[-4]